# White box appearing when I open Google maps

Tags: css, google-maps

I have hidden a hidden Google map on a page. When I click a link to open the map, the map opens, but I also get a strange white box appearing over other content else where on the page.

This appears to be something to do with the table which contains the google map.

You can see what I'm talking about by clicking on "Search Google Maps".

[on this page](http://dev2.whygo.com.au/searchWhiteBox.html).

Answer (score 0):

the cause of this problem was that there the google maps were contained inside 2 nested tables.

the outer table had a fixed height image being stretched to create a faux column on the left had side. Some how when the containing marked increased in size it was either not causing a reflow, or it was some other issue.

I sovled the issue by using a better faux column technique on the innner table with a repeat-y 1px high image.

so this had nothing to do with google maps. I was misled by other posts, I had found regarding white boxes and google maps.